# How to implement content Geo-fencing in facebook messenger bot?

Tags: facebook, geofencing, facebook-messenger-bot, messenger

I want to share videos via subscription messages with my messenger bot. However the content I am willing to share is restrictive to certain countries only.

When posting a video, geo-fencing is straight forward and facebook allows you to select the countries the post will be visible at.

However when sharing content via messenger this gets tricky. Any workaround besides asking from the user to share their location?

Answer (score 0):

You could restrict countries of Facebook Apps in the developer console, Settings -> Advanced tab.